# Not able to infer what is being returned in this generic method

Tags: java, generics

I know the basics of generics in Java but this method I saw in my team's codebase threw me off.

```
default <T>ResponseEntity <T>  getDataCall(){
    log.info("Inside DataService");
    return null;
}
```

I know this method's return type is using generics, meaning it is returning an object of ResponseEntity class. But why does it have T in both the left hand side and right hand side of ResponseEntity? In most of the code, I see the generic type only on the right hand side. Can someone please explain how this generic method works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing on the left is introducing the generic. A generic variable only exists in a particular scope, and something has to introduce that scope. Normally, you have a generic class (or interface), and that class takes type arguments, and those type arguments are in scope for the duration of the class, so they can be used as the types of function arguments or return types.

But you can also have generic *functions*, which is what we do here. Let's consider the difference.

```
class Bar<T> { ... }

interface Foo<T> {
  Bar<T> getBar();
}
```

Here, we can have a `Foo<T>` (for some specific, concrete `T`), and `getBar` on that `Foo<T>` will always return a `Bar<T>`, for that *same* specific `T`. The type `T` is fixed at the moment we declare the type of the `Foo<T>` object. Now consider

```
class Bar<T> { ... }

interface Foo {
  <T> Bar<T> getBar();
}
```

This interface gives us a lot more control, but it's much harder to satisfy. Now we just have one `Foo`. A single instance of this `Foo` type (of which there's only one; I haven't said anything about `T` yet) can have its `getBar` return a `Bar<T>` for *any* `T` that the caller wants, and the caller could produce a `Bar<String>` and a `Bar<Integer>` from the *same* `Foo` object if they so chose. It's up to the caller at the call site of `getBar` to decide what `T` should be, not up to whoever instantiates the class.

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks a lot for the explanation and sorry for the delayed response !!!  Just having one doubt in John's statement. He said first <T> indicates  that the method has a generic argument named T.  Normally in Java, arguments are present inside method brackets right ? like for example method(a,b). Can you please clarify.

Comment: Yes, value arguments are enclosed in parentheses. But generic arguments are different. A generic argument will never be something like `2`, or `new MyObject()`. A generic argument is always a type, like `Integer` or `String`. Since they're fundamentally different, they're always wrapped in angled brackets `<>` to distinguish them syntactically.

Comment: Hi Silvio,
Thanks again for the swift response. 
So the method getDataCall which i mentioned in my post accepts a generic argument of type T and returns a response entity of type T.  Am I correct in understanding, please advise.

Comment: Exactly! In principle, callers always supply the type `T` when calling your function. Sometimes, Java is smart enough to infer type arguments, but since your example only has a `T` in the return position, not argument position, I would suspect Java will find that difficult to infer.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed clarification. Now I understand how it works :)
Have an nice day !!!

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace is misleading. It would be better if it were spaced like so:

```
default <T> ResponseEntity<T> getDataCall()
```

The first `<T>` indicates that the method has a generic argument named `T`. The second one is part of the return type, `ResponseEntity<T>`. If you look up the `ResponseEntity` type I expect you'll see that it takes a generic argument.

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks a lot for the explanation and sorry for the delayed response !!!  Just having one doubt in your statement. You said first <T> indicates  that the method has a generic argument named T.  Normally in Java, arguments are present inside method brackets right ? like for example method(a,b). Can you please clarify.